# Having issue using Julia library

Tags: julia, knn

I am trying to run this code in Julia to calculate the knn value, but I get the following error when I run it.

****ERROR: LoadError: syntax: extra token "ScikitLearn" after end of expression
Stacktrace:
[1] top-level scope
@ e:\Fontbonne\CIS 585 Independent Study\Code\knn.jl:6
in expression starting at e:\Fontbonne\CIS 585 Independent Study\Code\knn.jl:6****

The error seems to be the library on line 6. I have searched for a couple of hours to try and find a solution.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code:

```
import Pkg
Pkg.add("ScikitLearn")
using ScikitLearn: fit!, predict, @sk_import
using DataFrames, CSV, DataStructures

from ScikitLearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from ScikitLearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from ScikitLearn.metrics import accuracy_score

function splitTrainTest(data, at = 0.8)
    n = nrow(data)
    ind = shuffle(1:n)
    train_ind = view(ind, 1:floor(Int, at*n))
    test_ind = view(ind, (floor(Int, at*n)+1):n)
    return data[train_ind,:], data[test_ind,:]
end

# data preparation

df = open("breast-cancer.data") do file
    read(file, String)
 end
print(df)
X, y = splitTrainTest(df)


# split data into train and test
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8)

# make model
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(x_train, y_train)

# check accuracy
print(accuracy_score(y_test, knn.predict(x_test)))
```

Comment: That's not valid Julia syntax, it's Python syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That comment should have been an answer: You're doing

```
from ScikitLearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
```

which is Python syntax, not Julia syntax. If you're trying to use a Python model in ScikitLearn.jl you probably want the `@sk_import` macro, in your case:

```
julia> @sk_import neighbors: KNeighborsClassifier
PyObject <class 'sklearn.neighbors._classification.KNeighborsClassifier'>
```

Comment: Hi Nils, thank you for the response (and you BatWannaBe), put your code and I now get this error!       ERROR: LoadError: syntax: character literal contains multiple characters
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope
   @ e:\Fontbonne\CIS 585 Independent Study\Code\knn.jl:6
in expression starting at e:\Fontbonne\CIS 585 Independent Study\Code\knn.jl:6

Comment: Here is the modified code                                                                                  
@sk_import neighbors: KNeighborsClassifier
PyObject <'class sklearn.neighbors._classification.KNeighborsClassifier'>
using DataFrames, CSV, DataStructures

Comment: Did you comment the whole `PyObject <class ...` line into Julia? That's the error you'll get in that case: `julia> 'class sklearn.neighbors._classification.KNeighborsClassifier'
ERROR: syntax: character literal contains multiple characters`. This is because single quotes in Julia are for single characters, double quotes `"` are for strings. You should probably just close this question as solved and sign up to the Julia Discourse, as SO isn't the right place for line-by-line debugging of your code.

Comment: Good advice.  Thak you.